# Is there a way to prevent JSF from displaying previous/outdated content in h:selectManyMenu after validation error?

Tags: validation, jsf-2, lifecycle, selectmanymenu

I have a form with, say a text field and a multi-select field.

```
<h:form id="form2">
    <h:messages for="text3" />
    <h:inputText id="text3" value="#{danielBean.text3}" required="true"/>
    <br/>

    <h:messages for="select1" />
    <h:selectManyMenu id="select1" value="#{danielBean.selStrings}"
        style="height:8em;" required="true"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{danielBean.allStrings}" var="_item" itemLabel="#{_item} (length #{_item.length()})" />
    <br/>
    <p:commandButton
        value="Submit"
        action="#{danielBean.save()}"
        update=":form2"
    >
</h:form>
```

On submit, both get validated, and if validation is successful, the relevant variables in the backing bean are updated. Fair enough.

The problem happens when the validation (of the multi-select) is NOT successful. In my Bean, I have (particularly for the `List<String>`s `allStrings` and `selStrings`)...

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    text3 = "";

    allStrings.clear();
    allStrings.add("This");
    allStrings.add("is");
    allStrings.add("a");
    allStrings.add("test");

    selStrings.clear();
    selStrings.add("a");
}
```

...so that the multi-select has one pre-selected option. If the user unselects that option (i.e. no options chosen), the validation will -of course- fail, an error message will be displayed...

...**but the multiselect will not be empty. It will show the content from the bean, i.e. "a" selected.** This is confusing to the user - getting an error message "input required", and being shown a filled-out field.

This appears to be a feature of JSF's lifecycle, see [this article by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.no/2012/03/reset-non-processed-input-components-on.html):

"When JSF renders input components, then it will *first test if the submitted value is not null* and then display it, else if the local value is not null and then display it, else it will display the model value."

This works fine for the text field `text3`, because it submits as an empty string, not null.

The problem is that zero selected options from a multi-select means that the submitted value is null, that the local copy (I guess, since it's the first submit) is null, so that the model value ("a" selected) is displayed.

I do not want that.

**How can I force JSF to use the null value it got submitted when rendering the validation response?**

Thanks in advance
Antares42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution for this (other than reporting an issue to JSF guys and/or hacking in JSF source code). There's however a workaround: update only the components which really need to be updated on submit. Currently, you've set ajax to update the entire form. How about updating just the messages?

```
<h:messages id="text3_m" for="text3" />
...
<h:messages id="select1_m" for="select1" />
...
<p:commandButton ... update="text3_m select1_m" />
```

You can if necessary make use of [PrimeFaces Selectors](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf) to minimize the boilerplate if you have rather a lot of fields:

```
<h:messages for="text3" styleClass="messages" />
...
<h:messages for="select1" styleClass="messages" />
...
<p:commandButton ... update="@(.messages)" />
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, I will check whether the particular project allows it. Thanks, BalusC!

Comment: Man you're quick! :-) Anyway, because the live project needs to validate against data in the backing bean, we have now switched to bean-based validation entirely. In that case the model is always updated (and the validation runs in the application stage of the JSF lifecycle), so the problem with the ambiguous / unpredictable behavior of selects does not occur.